# How to define an undefined number of variables in python?

Tags: python, arrays, variables

I have been solving a Python problem and I can't find out how to define an undefined number of variables. This is the code I used to define a define number of variables (2).

```
h1, m1 = map(int, input().split())
```

So, how would you set an undefined number of variables. In this example, I want there to be n number of variables within h.

```
n = int(input())
h = int(input().split)
```

How could I do it? I am new to programming in Python, so I would to have as much help as possible.

Comment: What do you mean by an undefined number of variables?  Are you sure you don't just want a list?

Comment: I was also going to recommend a list: http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/python/3942-arrays-in-python.html

Comment: `h = map(int, input().split())` or `h = list(map(int, input().split())` in python3 will give you a list  of ints, you already know how to do this so what exactly are you asking?l

Comment: "I want there to be n number of variables within h" sounds like the number of variables _is_ defined. Also, what does "...I used to define a define number of variables" mean?

Comment: Can you give us an [mcve] of what do you want? For example, the input and the expect output?

Answer (score 0):

```
h = [int(n) for n in input().split()]
```

This makes a list, applying the **int** conversion to each word of the split input.  With an arbitrary quantity of input values, you use an expandable list, not individual variable names.